# Can't resolve all parameters for Component: (?, [object Object], [object Object])

Tags: angular, parameters, components, runtime

In Angular 4 I have defined a new component and put it in the app.module.ts

```
  import {
BodyComponent,//new component
FooterComponent,
GlobalRestService,
HeaderComponent,
HttpService,
InsuranceSharedModule,
PreLoaderComponent,
PreloaderService,
} from './shared';
```

But I have encountered the following error.Similar to this error occurred in GitHab. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-aws/issues/34

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BodyComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15781)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15649)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15244)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15106)
at compiler.es5.js:26833
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at compiler.es5.js:26832
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26829)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)
at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536)
at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4522)
at main (main.browser.ts:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.browser.ts:40)
at Object.module.exports (main.browser.ts:46)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b82d5be055c3e9968a46:707)
at fn (bootstrap b82d5be055c3e9968a46:112)
at Object.defineProperty.value (TimerObservable.js:107)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b82d5be055c3e9968a46:707)
at bootstrap b82d5be055c3e9968a46:805
at main.bundle.js:810[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The provided code is insufficient to reproduce the issue

Comment: sometimes this issue will be because of missing import in app.modules.ts. check whether all the components, providers used in that page are imported in app modules.

Comment: Try stopping the project and run again. It helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved, this error occurs when we define a  `navcontroller` in component `constructor` Which is not imported correctly.

In BodyComponent.ts:

```
import { GlobalRestService } from '../../../shared/services';

constructor(
    private global: GlobalRestService,
    private router: Router,
) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

'../../../shared/services' was not correct URL.